# IfxPy module import error after succesfull installation

Tags: python

I am experiencing an issue with IfxPy installation.
The operating system is windows 64 bit and the 64-bit version of Python 3.7.4 is runned.
After pip installation of  the wheel file IfxPy-3.0.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl from  - https://pypi.org/project/IfxPy/#files  the pip list command or help(modules) command from interpreteur shows that the module is installed:

```
>>> help("modules") 
Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules... IfxPy [...other modules...]
```

I try to find the location of the module, and it is

```
>>> imp.find_module('IfxPy') (<_io.BufferedReader name='C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\IfxPy.pyd'>,
'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\IfxPy.pyd', ('.pyd', 'rb', 3))
```

The PATH environmental variable contains the abovementioned path.
However, when I try to import the module from IDLE interpreteur I get the error:

```
>>> import IfxPy 
Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
     import IfxPy ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be  found.
```

What could be the potential source of the error and how can it be solved? Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you install [informix client SDK](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016673), which needs to be installed as a dependency, according to the [README](https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy)

Comment: Thank you very much, the issue was with the informix client SDK.